# What kind of gas shut off valve is this and how do you use it?

Tags: gas, shutoff

I was wondering how to use this gas shut off valve. It looks like it requires a special type of key but I have had no luck in finding out what type of tool I need.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How far might you need to turn it?  90 degrees?  Several full rotations?   And how urgently?  If this is the emergency shut off you might want to leave a handle attached permanently ready for when time is short.

Comment: It can be turned with any wrench.  More interesting is what the detents and hole are for.  Is the red knob spring-loaded on its shaft, can you move it in and out along the shaft?  Is there a notch or something to engage those detents somewhere out of camera shot?   Anyway it looks like those are somehow meant to lock it in position, I just can't see how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is it**

Pictured is a "flat/square head" valve knob.  Its purpose is to prevent operation by hand or by accident, but to allow operation by almost any large enough wrench or flathead screwdriver.   You would use it where you want to prevent accidental or mischievous operation but without providing any real security or requiring special tools or keys.

The small hole is so you can install a handle on it and secure that with a cotter pin.

I don't know what the strange detents are for.   Maybe the same knob is used for other valves.

**How do you use it**

Turn it, with anything at all capable of grabbing the square head or the flat slot in the front.

Comment: Thank you this answer really helped!!

Answer (score 12):

Looks like a plain old adjustable open end wrench (or an open end wrench of the correct size) will operate it. Wrench on the square bit of the red part, turn the whole red part, probably 90 degrees.

A nail, rod, or Allen wrench of the right general size might also work by going through the holes.

Comment: It also looks like a very wide flat-blade screwdriver or other similar object might work, as there's two slots visible in the last picture.

Comment: The quickest, simplest, and most likely tool to be in the house of the inexperienced DIYer would be to stick a screwdriver through the two holes and turn.

Comment: @FreeMan An "inexperienced DIYer" mucking about with a gas valve is a bit terrifying!

Comment: Shutting one off in an emergency is good to be able to do even with very limited experience. Turning it back on is a different matter.

Comment: So I shouldn't tell you, @SteveWellens, about having hooked up my own gas water heater many years ago? ;) (Yes, I tested for leaks with soapy water about 4 times before lighting...)

Answer (score 3):

How big is the hole through the side?  Leverage can be gained by using a screwdriver or even a suitably-sized nail through that hole and (presumably) the one opposite.

An 8 or 12 pointed socket should engage the four points on the square as well.

For limited access, a ring-spanner of appropriate size should get you in there eventually, but you might want a ratchetting one or patience.  Your access looks good in the photos though.

---

But the "proper" or original tool for these is an **alligator wrench** which is intended for use on square bolts and nuts.

[image]

---

Personally if I was doing this a lot, I'd use parallel-jaw plumbers pliers like [these knipex ones](https://www.knipex.com/products/pipe-wrenches-and-water-pump-pliers/pliers-wrenches-pliers-and-a-wrench-in-a-single-tool/pliers-wrenchespliers-and-wrench-single-tool/8603250)  The only downside  are Price, and that you have to reset every 90 degrees of turn.  Minimum is 60 degrees and a lot of resets.

[image]

---

And the final option is to cut a disk of wood, and drill-then-file a square hole to take the square shaft.  This gives you a handle that could be left in place for quick action as long as the required hand-pressure is not excessive.

Comment: The alligator wrench, I think, is actually a kind of pipe wrench, for use on "black iron" (soft steel) pipes, where its teeth can cut in. I'm thinking it would make a mess out of a square nut. But the parallel-aw pliers are excellent; I have a pair and they're among my favourite tools.

Comment: All three of these proposed "tools" seem worse than a bog-standard adjustable wrench. (the knipex is fine but as you note quite expensive)

Answer (score 1):

They sell specific "gas shut off tool"s for shutting off gas valves in emergencies. For example, this is a common design that can be used to shut off both gas and water:

[image]

Comment: What would be the name of this specific tool, should someone be interested in procuring one?

Comment: @maxathousand The pictured item appears to be an [ER™ Multi-use Emergency Utility Shut Off Tool](https://www.quakekare.com/er-multi-use-emergency-utility-shut-off-tool-8s).

Comment: I inherited a similar tool for the house I purchased. The "diagonal rectangle" fits the shut off at my meter. The other "tuning fork" end might fit your indoor valve perfectly. But as others noted, some cresent wrench or adjustable pliers might be in your tool chest.

Comment: This is a generic tool for use in emergencies.   This answer does not address the peculiar features of OP's valve knob.   In fact, it's not obvious that this tool would even work with that.

Comment: @jay613 you're not wrong, the problem is that OP doesn't give any dimensions, so how can any of us say whether a tool we propose will fit?

Comment: I would think, @jay613, that the flat-blade screwdriver portion of the "hammer head" would likely fit across the slots of the OP's valve, but you are correct that without any dimensions on the valve or this tool, nobody knows. I'd say, though, that generally speaking this is _highly likely_ to do the trick.

Comment: Sure of course, but the question is not "is there a general purpose tool that could possibly be used to forcibly gain access to and then rotate this unusual knob in an emergency", but it is the *opposite* ... what is this unusual knob for and how is it *meant* to be used?